# Why is Mosaic or Mosaic To New Image causing a 1-pixel gap between adjacent images?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, raster, arcpy, mosaic

I have a series of adjacent PNG images, and I'm trying to merge/mosaic them into a single seamless image. The images have clean "cuts" between them, with no overlaps.

However, when I use either the Mosaic or Mosaic To New Image tools, a 1-pixel gap has been inserted between some sets of images (but not between all sets of images):

[image]

Identifying within the gap shows Nodata. Here is the line in Python which creates the Mosaic:

```
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(list_of_images,outputImage,"#","8_BIT_UNSIGNED","#",1,"LAST","FIRST")
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I need to check/change to avoid this gap?

Thanks

Comment: I get all sorts of artifacts when using these tools with  file geodatabase grids or outputting to FGDB.  My workaround is to work with grids outside the GDB.

Comment: @Jakub it's weird that I'm seeing the exact opposite - it works well in a file GDB, but gives me an artifact outside of this

Comment: I am leaning towards a bug as well. I am now georeferencing and mosiacing about 70 images and running into this problem no matter how I do it, tiff, FGDB, Grids - what works for a set of 10 images does not work for the next set of images. Frustrating.

Comment: ArcGIS haiku: yesterday it worked. today it isn't working. Esri is like that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A successful workaround was to create a new file geodatabase, and write the mosaic image to this - the gap is now gone, with no other changes to the code.

This may be a bug, or perhaps there's a problem with using PNG files as the output?